# Why am I getting lots of padding above table-cell div

Tags: html, css

I've got two table-cell divs next to each other, but for some reason one has what seems to be a giant margin-top that I'm not creating, and I don't have any idea why.

```
<div style="display:table;">
<div style="display:table-cell;">
    <img src="http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/3181865974/b3583cd60d3d21ea9b9776634084b710_normal.png" />
</div>
<div style="display:table-cell;">
    <div>Your compiler finds a big block of commented-out code… It knows it shouldn't look… Takes the tiniest of tiny peeks… BLUSHES BRIGHT RED.Your compiler finds a big block of commented-out code… It knows it shouldn't look… Takes the tiniest of tiny peeks… BLUSHES BRIGHT RED.</div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HycBx/

Comment: add vertical-align: top; to your style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default vertical alignment for the cells is the baseline.  You will notice that the image and the first line of the text actually share the same baseline, hence the alignment.  This is irrespective of the `display` property, and you can see  the same behavior without splitting the display into cells:

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/HycBx/2/

The simplest fix is probably to change both cells to have the same vertical alignment.  I think `vertical-align: middle` works best.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/HycBx/3/

Comment: *sighs at CSS in general*  because OF COURSe the default alignment is the bottom

Comment: @zacaj there's a difference between the bottom and the baseline.  In fact, `vertical-align: bottom` probably looks how you want it.

Answer (score 4):

You have both cells with the same height. The space on top is because the text is defaulting to a vertical align of "baseline".

Add the css to your cells:

```
vertical-align: top;
```

Comment: For the record the default value is baseline, not bottom.